# Problems with Go Appengine endpoint tests

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am trying to create an endpoint test when using appengine. Unfortunately, the tests keep failing because of the lack of a schema (and host) within the url used when creating the test `*Request` struct. When running appengine tests a server is spawned for that specific test that runs on a semi-random port number, which makes it seemingly impossible to define the full url to perform the test on.

The [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/localunittesting/) on running tests like this are very sparse and only give half of an example, so I am left scratching my head on how to get this to work.

This is the error that I get from the marked line within the code snippet

`Error: Received unexpected error "Post /auth: unsupported protocol scheme \"\""`

**Test Code**

```
func TestEndpoints_Auth(t *testing.T) {

    // input data
    account := Account{
        AuthProvider:   "facebook",
        AuthProviderId: "123345456",
    }
    b, _ := json.Marshal(&account)
    reader := bytes.NewReader(b)

    // test server
    inst, err := aetest.NewInstance(nil)
    if !assert.NoError(t, err) { return }
    defer inst.Close()

    // request
    client := http.Client{}
    req, err := inst.NewRequest("POST", "/auth", reader)
    if !assert.NoError(t, err) { return }
    req.Header.Add(AppAuthToken, "foobar")
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if !assert.NoError(t, err) { return }   // <=== Where the error occurs

    // tests
    if !assert.Nil(t, err) { return }
    assert.Equal(t, http.StatusCreated, resp.StatusCode)
}
```

Logs

`[GIN-debug] POST   /auth                     --> bitbucket.org/chrisolsen/chriscamp.(*endpoints).Auth-fm (5 handlers)
[GIN-debug] GET    /accounts/me              --> bitbucket.org/chrisolsen/chriscamp.(*endpoints).GetMyAccount-fm (7 handlers)
INFO     2016-04-22 13:23:39,278 devappserver2.py:769] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2016-04-22 13:23:39,278 devappserver2.py:785] DEFAULT_VERSION_HOSTNAME will not be set correctly with --port=0
WARNING  2016-04-22 13:23:39,345 simple_search_stub.py:1126] Could not read search indexes from c:\users\chris\appdata\local\temp\appengine.testapp\search_indexes
INFO     2016-04-22 13:23:39,354 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:54461
INFO     2016-04-22 13:23:41,043 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:54462
INFO     2016-04-22 13:23:41,046 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:54466`

Comment: I think you may not need NewInstance, instead create [aetest.NewContext()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/localunittesting/), and use that context to call the external facebook service using [URL Fetch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/urlfetch/)

Comment: Gettting a `context` pointer works if you are testing a method/service that requires a context pointer (memcache, datastore, email, etc), but using an instance to test an endpoint is the only way I can find to create a `http.Request` that works, but then the docs are pretty weak so there might be a way that isn't shown.

Answer (score 0):

I was really hoping to perform api blackbox tests, but that *seems* to be undoable with appengine. Instead I am now performing the tests on the endpoint directly.

```
req, _ := inst.NewRequest("POST", "/auth", reader)
req.Header.Add(AppAuthToken, "foobar")
resp := httptest.NewRecorder()

handlePostAuth(resp, req)
assert.Equal(t, http.StatusCreated, resp.Code)
```